# Replace ; outside of tags (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have the following HTML output which I can't change:

```
<td class="test"><a>link1</a>;<a></a>;<a></a>;<a>link</a><td>
```

How can I get rid of the ; so the result becomes:

link1; link2

This is my best attempt:

```
var test = new String($(this).html());
var tmp = ">; <A><"
test = test.replace(/tmp/g,"><A><");
```

Comment: If you have a string that contains `>;<a><`, why are you trying to find `>; <A><`?

Comment: could you detail the wanted result a little more?

Answer (score 3):

You can just look through the [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) `<a>` elements and remove them along with their next sibling `";"` text nodes in a loop, like this:

```
$(".test a:empty").each(function() {
    if(this.nextSibling.nodeValue == ";") 
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.nextSibling);
}).remove();
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QdMhj/).

This just gets the empty anchors, and just before removing them from the DOM, loops through to look at their trailing text nodes to see if they are explicitly `";"` in content...if that's the case then we remove that text node from the parent `<td>`.  Then after that loop, we remove all the empty anchors we found in the first place.

Comment: Tnx. Got it to work, however only in IE9 and Chrome, not in IE8